# How Arrays.asList(...).contains(...) works?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

**I have the following code..**

```
    String[] weekEnds={"0","6"};

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){

    if(Arrays.asList(weekEnds).contains(i)){

     System.out.println("I am in the array");       
    }    
  }
```

but its not going into the if condition ..i dont know where im going wrong..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Becuase a String with `"0"` is not the same as an Integer which is `0`. In fact `(Long) 0L`, `(Integer) 0)` and `(Double) 0.0` are not the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either change the `if` condition to

```
if(Arrays.asList(weekEnds).contains(String.valueOf(i))){
```

Or change your array to

```
Integer[] weekEnds={0,6};
```

Answer (score 7):

You're comparing Strings and ints. Your array contains Strings (`"0"`, `"6"`), but you're passing an int into the comparison.

That int will be [boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to an Integer, but an `Integer(1)` does not equal `"1"`

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing apples and oranges (in this case `String`s and `Integer`s).

You are converting an array of `String` into a `List`. Then you call `contains()` on it with an `int` value. Because the method takes `Object` as the parameter type, the `int` gets autoboxed into an `Integer`.

In order to fix this, write:

```
if(Arrays.asList(weekEnds).contains("" + i)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have an int array to be able to do such a comparison.

Change this:

```
String[] weekEnds={"0","6"};
```

to

```
int[] weekEnds = {0,6};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change to `Integer[] weekEnds={0,6};` and I think, it will work.