# Java- Syntax error on token "!=", Name expected after this token

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple calculator and keep on getting the error in the title when I try to make it show "error" if the user doesn't enter one of the given types of operation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class experiments {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String operation;
        double fNum, sNum, ans;

        //select type of operation
        System.out.println("Type addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division, then press enter");
        operation = userInput.nextLine();
        if (operation!=("addition","subtraction","multiplication","division")) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

        //enter numbers
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        fNum = userInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        sNum = userInput.nextDouble();

        //calculate
        if (operation.equals("addition")) {
            ans=fNum + sNum;
        }
        else if (operation.equals("subtraction")) { 
            ans=fNum - sNum;
        }
        else if (operation.equals("multiplication")){
            ans=fNum * sNum;
        }
        else if (operation.equals("division")) {
            ans=fNum/sNum;
        }
        //print answer
        System.out.println("The answer is ");
        System.out.println(ans);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare things to a group of objects like this:

```
operation!=("addition","subtraction","multiplication","division")
```

Presumably what you want is "if `operation` is not one of these four things". You've got a few options. The one most like what you have now is to make a new `ArrayList` (say `legalOperations`) containing your four legal operations, and then use `legalOperations.contains(operation)`.

However, a cleaner way, which is "better Java", would be to make an `enum` and use that to do your comparisons.

```
public enum LegalOperations {
    ADDITION,
    SUBTRACTION,
    MULTIPLICATION,
    DIVISION
}
```

Then you could do your comparisons to your enum (perhaps you'd give the enum a constructor to allow it to have a clear String value for each enum constant, and an `isLegalOperation` method, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Java is not capable of understand this command...

```
if (operation!=("addition","subtraction","multiplication","division")) {
```

Instead, you need to check each one individually...

```
if (!"addition".equals(operation) &&
    !"subtraction".equals(operation) &&
    !"multiplication".equals(operation) &&
    !"division".equals(operation)) {
    // Handle error...
}
```

Comment: I believe you want `&&`, otherwise one of the first two is guaranteed to be true.

Comment: @Kevin I could have just wrapped it in a single !(...) block :P

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone, I found this to be the easiest since I haven't really learned arrays yet, so thank you for this very easy to understand code

Comment: @user2526522: See also [*De Morgan's_laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 1):

You should create `ArrayList` and put value there.
Then you can check if the value exists in the `ArrayList`.
Like that:
[How Arrays.asList(...).contains(...) works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979700/how-arrays-aslist-contains-works)

Comment: Also, I think it would be `List#contains`, no need to use `Arrays` as it's already a `List` :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are right. But maybe the author wishes to create list from array first. :)

Answer (score 0):

`if (operation!=("addition","subtraction","multiplication","division"))` is incorrect comparison in Java. Use `switch` statement if you are using Java 7 or `string.equals` method with multiple if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains method like this:

```
String[] operations = {"addition","subtraction","multiplication","division"};
if(!operations.contains(operation)) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite the same as

```
if (!(    operation.equals("addition") || operation.equals("subtraction") ||
          operation.equals("multiplication") || operation.equals("division"))) {
                System.out.println("error");
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this print error even if one these conditions are true?

Comment: @AmalMurali even if one of these conditions is true, the final result to the if statement is false. If the specified input is not one of the conditions, then the final result to if is tru and it prints the error

Answer (score 0):

There is one more Easy way of doing it which involves writing less

as you have an array of Strings, Declare it as an array

```
String [] operations = {"addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", "division"};
```

then use this to check

> 

```
 if(!Arrays.asList(operations).contains(operation)) {
   System.out.println("error");
 }
```

Comment: It would easier (IMHO) to create a `List`, then you don't need to keep creating temporary, short lived objects each time you want to make a comparisions